# Read data from a txt.file and print out its 2D array contents

Tags: c, arrays, file

I need some help, I would like to print out information from a file (in characters)

I decided to use a 2D array since the data looks something like this

```
0 0 . . . 
0 0 . . . 
. . . . . 
. . . . . 
. . . . .
```

It seems that I cannot print them out with the code that I have prepared now

please see below:

```
/* Read from file, pass on file contents to a 2D array, Print file contents from 2D array*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define N 5


//My proposed function to print an array with contents from a file
void printboard(int **a, int n, int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char linestr[100];
    int board[N][N];
    int k;
    int h=0, l=0; 
    if(argc==2) //File should be called from the terminal hence working with argc & argv
    {
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");


     if(fp == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Error, can't open '%s' file!!!\n", argv[1]);
            return -1;
        }
    while (fgets(linestr,sizeof linestr, fp) != NULL)
        for(k=0; k<strlen(linestr); k++)
        {
            if (linestr[k]!='\n')
            {
                board[h][l]=(int)linestr[k];
                l++;


            }
            h++;
            l=0;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printboard(board,h,l);

return 0;
}

void printboard(int **a, int n, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i< N; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j< N; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

I have very basic knowledge in C and only began coding 1.5 months ago. Is there any advice from the community how I can fix this or do it better? The aim is to print contents of a file in a 2D array format. I would really like to have the data work with 2D array because I need to work further on it to move the '0' in a game called Peg Solitaire.

Comment: despite the fact that you have 2 unused parameters with the same name in your printboard method, can you be more precise on whats wrong/whats expected ?

Comment: I assume that you are referring to int n; that appears twice in the print board function

Comment: This is really too much code. In the future, pare it down to a minimal example. IN the process you may find the bug yourself.

Comment: I assume that you are referring to int n; that appears twice in the print board function, the issue is with the compiler it gives me the following error: redefinition of parameter n
sol1.c:7: note: previous definition of n was here
sol1.c: In function main:
sol1.c:40: warning: passing argument 1 of printboarb from incompatible pointer type
sol1.c:7: note: expected int **but argument is of type int (*)[5]
sol1.c: At top level:
sol1.c:45: error: redefinition of parameter n
sol1.c:45: note: previous definition of n was here
I really have no idea how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Argument names in functions must be unique.  So your printboard function cannot have two "n" arguments, you'll have to change one name (to "m" or something).  Also, since you're printing n x n matrices and you have defined "N" via the preprocessor, do you even need those arguments? :)

The passing of the array (first argument of printboard) is a bit trickier and requires some knowledge of how pointers and memory work.  See discussion here:

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/97898-passing-2-dimensional-array-function.html

What this boils down to is changing your function definition to:

```
void printboard(int a[][N], int m, int n);
```

One little thing: in order to print your numbers you probably want to print them as integers rather than characters so you should change

```
printf("%c", a[i][j]);
```

to

```
printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
```

I added the space so the numbers would run together when print out to the terminal.

As far as parsing the input, that's a whole nuther topic.  I'd suggest strtok to break up your lines as you read them from the file.  Then you'll use something like sscanf to store the data into your board array.  See these refs:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: I experimented without the two arguments and with N #defined it seems to compile properly, however now I seem to be printing out of the buffer when I use "%c", in the function which is now void printboard(int a[][N]), and ascii codes when "%d " is used, I will review your links though thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am just guessing here that you want points (.) displayed when the field is empty
so prefill your board array.

```
char board[N][N]; // i changed it to char, was int but char is enough
memset(board, '.', sizeof(board));
```